# Display:flex and Firefox

Tags: css, flexbox

I found this mobile flexbox grid at CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lmohH

It works in all mobile browsers but Firefox. It doesn't get the `margin: 2%`, which only works when disabling the `display:flex` in the class "row".

I know that some browsers uses the old flexbox, but why should this affect a thing like margin?

Comment: You can add the `margin-bottom` to `.row` instead and it should work the same.  I'm not sure why it's not working the same in Firefox, though'

Comment: This looks like a Firefox specific bug (note that this is in the current desktop version as well).  If you change the margin to use any unit other than a percentage, it works as expected.  If the version you're using still has support for only the old specification, there are *many* bugs to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks. We're targeting mostly newer browsers, so it should be ok. I'll try to make a workaround until they fix that issue.